# Julia using Slurm invokes only one node

Tags: parallel-processing, julia, slurm

```
srun --nodes=3 hostname
```

returns successfully all the 3 node names but

```
srun --nodes=3 julia test.jl
```

fails with error below where test.jl is given at the end here

Worker 2 terminated.
ERROR (unhandled task failure): Version read failed. Connection closed by peer.
Stacktrace:
 [1] process_hdr(::TCPSocket, ::Bool) at ./distributed/process_messages.jl:257
 [2] message_handler_loop(::TCPSocket, ::TCPSocket, ::Bool) at ./distributed/process_messages.jl:143
 [3] process_tcp_streams(::TCPSocket, ::TCPSocket, ::Bool) at ./distributed/process_messages.jl:118
 [4] (::Base.Distributed.##99#100{TCPSocket,TCPSocket,Bool})() at ./event.jl:73

srun: error: n-0-2: task 2: Exited with exit code 1
srun: error: n-0-0: task 0: Exited with exit code 1
srun: error: n-0-2: task 2: Exited with exit code 1
srun: error: n-0-1: task 1: Exited with exit code 1

test.jl

```
using ClusterManagers

addprocs(SlurmManager(3), partition="slurm", t="00:5:00")

hosts = []
pids = []
for i in workers()
        host, pid = fetch(@spawnat i (gethostname(), getpid()))
        println(host)
        push!(hosts, host)
        push!(pids, pid)
end


# The Slurm resource allocation is released when all the workers have
# exited
for i in workers()
        rmprocs(i)
end
```

Why?
Note: I do not have julia as module but julia is in a shared directory accessible by all nodes.

Comment: I believe that ClusterManagers.jl calls `srun` for you. So the way I would call the script is just a simple `julia test.jl`. The line `addprocs` takes care of submitting the job with SLURM and with the parameters you pass to it.

Comment: In that case @juliohm, I get srun: error: node-0-2: tasks 0-2: Exited with exit code 2